# What are the situations where AWS Lambda is not the answer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

AWS heavily markets Lambda like it's the end all be all answer to writing code but I read from others online that it is not suitable for all scenarios. In what situations would I not want to use AWS lambda for running code?

I've used lambda functions before and they seem to work for all my use cases. Trying to understand when we would not want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

From this Reddit [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/ekyj1a/please_use_the_right_tool_for_each_job_serverless/), AWS Lambda is not suitable for

1.) Extremely low-latency workloads. (e.g. AdTech where things needs to be computed in 100ms or less).

2.) Workloads that are sensitive to cold-starts. No matter whether you use provisioned capacity or not, you will feel the pain of a cold-start. Java and .NET are of prime concern here. It takes seconds for them to cold-start. If your customer clicks a button on a website and has to wait 5 seconds for something to happen you'll lose that customer in a heartbeat.

3.) Lambda functions that open connection pools. Not only does this step add additional time to the cold-start, but there's not clean way of closing those connections since Lambda doesn't provide 'onShutdown' hooks.

4.) Workloads that are constantly processing data, non-stop. Do your cost calculations. You will notices that Lambda functions will become extremely expensive if you have a 100 of them running at the same time, non-stop, 100% of the time. Those 100 Lambda functions could be replaced with one Fargate container. Don't forget that one instance of a Lambda function can process only 1 request at a time.

5.) Long-running processes.

6.) Workloads that require websockets. There's just too many complexities when it comes to websockets, you add a lot more if you use Lambdas that are short-lived. People have done it, but I wouldn't suggest it.

7.) Workloads that require a lot of storage (e.g. they consistently download and upload data). You will run out of storage, and it's painful.

It seems that AWS Lambda is most suitable for sparse/bursty type workloads that do not meet any of the criteria above.